# Accessing other applications android

Tags: android, google-maps

i am new to android developing so please go easy on me.  I have searched extensively about trying to access information from another running application to use in my application.

To be more specific, i am trying to access a Google maps application and get some information from it.  Information such as, is the user en-route to a destination? And are they using the walk, bike or drive feature?  I have my idea for my app and i think ill be able to do everything, its just accessing this running application and cant seem to find any information on how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot actually access the other app's data - the obvious reason is privacy and security (imagine if you could access Facebook's data or Tinder's data and sell them to advertisers).

The only way you can access app's data in Android if the app declares the data that is available. That is done via Content Providers and that is how you can access contacts in the phone, for example. For more details see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html.

Of course, there's another way, and that is that the company that has the data gives you structured access to it, and Google does that with their Maps API. I haven't used the V2 API and I don't think you can get all the data you'd want, but there's an Activity Recognition part so at least something is available. You can find more details here: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and taking the time to answer. I will look into your suggestions.